# Why do I see a static text before animation in my tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm adding simple stack animation to my `tableViewCell` which animates like `cells` are being add to a stack. When I tap the `UIButton` that segues me to the `tableView` I first see a static cell which has my values and then after a small gap my animation works. I don't know why my `tableView` shows that `cell` before animation ? Here is my code for the VC :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    animateTable()
}

func animateTable() {

    let cells = tableView.visibleCells
    let tableHeight: CGFloat = tableView.bounds.size.height

    for i in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = i as UITableViewCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tableHeight)
    }

    var index = 0

    for a in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = a as UITableViewCell
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0);
        }, completion: nil)

        index += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `view` appears, it would have the `UITableView` data already populated via a call to `reloadData`. You do the `animation` only after the `view` appears. So at that point, you'll see the existing data for a fraction of a second and then the `animation` would kick in.

If you don't want the data to appear at all before the `animation` runs, you might want to not show data as soon as the `view` loads by doing something like the following - this might not be the best solution, but it is the easiest to implement:

1: Add a new variable to indicate whether you've run the `animation` or not.

```
var wasAnimated = false
```

2: Check this variable in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `return 0` if the `animation` has not run yet.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !wasAnimated {
        return 0
    }
    // Rest of the original code
}
```

3: Set the flag at the beginning of `animateTable` and then `reloadData` before you execute the rest of the `animation` code.

```
func animateTable() {
    wasAnimated = true
    tableView.reloadData()
    // The rest of the original code    
}
```

That should get you the behaviour you wanted :)

Comment: It's great that you want to help, upvoted you for that. But make sure you ask the OP to paste the code in the question and not link to the code outside of SO so others can benefit from the answer and question.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/raunakstrikha/0a92bbf8ee6fcecc438d77deb5bd5b61 here is the code, Thank you.

Comment: @S.Verma I've added a code solution to my answer. That works the way you wanted. The code markup is a bit messed up though and I'll try to correct it but not sure if I'll succeed. Hopefully, this gives you the general idea :)

Comment: @Sneak I just needed the additional code to test if my solution would work -  I hate just giving an answer without verifying if it works :) The additional code was not really relevant to the answer since the answer mostly uses the code posted in the question.

Comment: @Fahim Yeah I saw, great job! Keep it up :)

Comment: Works perfectly fine.